# Gnome: run program w/o window decorations

Tags: linux, gnome, xorg, metacity

I'd like to run [RealVNC 3.3.7](http://www.realvnc.com/products/free/3.3.7/man/vncviewer.html) without window decorations **without** using the `-fullscreen` option. My system is Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.4 running GNOME. Is this an Xt option, a Metacity option, a GTK option, what? Is this something I can even control externally without modifying the GUI application?

I thought this would work but it doesn't appear to have any effect:

```
vncviewer -xrm '*wmDecorationWidth:0' :1
```

Answer (score 1):

It mostly depends on the window manager. (Although it can be controlled by GTK, in the end it's up to the WM.)

If you use Compiz, I believe you can specify exceptions using [CCSM](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM).

Metacity does not have such an option.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> The *wmii* window manager comes with a tool called `wihack`, which is able to override the window type of a program.

For example, **`wihack -type toolbar vncviewer`**. Even though the tool is part of *wmii*, EWMH window types are used by most window managers **including Metacity**.